# How can i stop HtmlAgilityPack changing the source of the loaded page?

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to load html file like this:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionOutputOriginalCase = true;
doc.Load(@"c:\ftp\file3.html");
```

then i'm using xpath to select node and get outerHTML but the problem is that i get a modified page source, for example i get :

```
<font class="hello" id="price">
```

when on real page source it's

```
<font class=hello id=price>
```

how do i avoid that ?

Comment: I think HTML agility pack is simply auto correcting badly formatted HTML, most browsers will do a similar thing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  At least not when using a DOM parser.

The HTML Agility Pack in this case is taking the string input and doing its best to create a valid DOM from that input.  This is not valid:

```
<font class=hello id=price>
```

So it translates it into something that is valid:

```
<font class="hello" id="price">
```

It will attempt to do the same for any and all invalid markup in the HTML.  If you don't want to use valid markup, then a DOM parser probably isn't the right tool for the job.  At that point you're working with a custom string input and you'd have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Is there any other option scrapping a web page and detecting tags (and the innerText that between them) easily without modifying source ?

Comment: @user2396640: I don't see how the DOM parsing is preventing you from doing that.  If you want to parse HTML, then the parser first has to convert the input into valid HTML.  If you want to parse some custom string which isn't really HTML but kind of looks like it, you're on your own.

Comment: so.. maybe i'll use it any way if you know how to tell me how to reach to the innerText of something "complicated" as that using xpath : <font class="perur colorBlack"><nobr><font class="perurblack">innerTEXT</font></nobr></font>